# How to redirect console output of ncftpget to log?

Tags: redirect, console, output, ncftp

I would like to capture the progress information during downloads.
I have tried, for example from a cmd prompt:

```
c:\Windows\ncftpget ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1MB.zip > mylog
c:\Windows\ncftpget ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1MB.zip >> mylog
c:\Windows\ncftpget ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/1MB.zip > mylog 2>&1
```

Mylog is always written with 0 bytes, unless the file to be downloaded is already present.  In that case I get a 92 byte error message.
The problem seems specific to ncftpget. It works with Windows 10 ftp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -d /path/to/log.txt

```
ncftpget -d /tmp/ncftpget.log <url>
```

> Example output:
>
> 2018-12-01 03:49:33  Cmd: USER anonymous
>   2018-12-01 03:49:33  331: Password required for anonymous
>   2018-12-01 03:49:33  Cmd: PASS NcFTP@
>   2018-12-01 03:49:35  530: Login incorrect
>   2018-12-01 03:49:35  Cmd: QUIT
>   2018-12-01 03:49:35  221: Goodbye

Comment: Thank you wuseman, much appreciated.  That gets me 75% of the solution.  I wanted to include also the ncftpget command itself with the options and url.   I guess I can send them to the log separately.  But I'm curious why the normal redirect methods don't work.